# Django Booleanfiedl Checkbox and Label displays in two lines

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I have a registration form with Django 1.8.  I am asking the user to select checkbox "I have read and agree to the Terms of Use". The issue is on the form the label and boolenfield checkbox are on two lines. For example "Terms&Conditions" 1st line, Checkbox and helptip - 2nd Line.  Is there any way to have all in one line like:

Terms&Condition [BooleanField]checkbox

forms.py

.....
iAgree = forms.BooleanField(label=_("Terms&Conditions"))

addm.html

...

```
    <p>          
         {{userform.iAgree.label_tag}}
         {{userform.iAgree}}
          <a title="Please accept that you have read the Terms of Use" href="#" class="helpIcon tooltip"><span title="help"></span></a> </label>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of this is likely due to your HTML.

Give this a try:

```
<p>
    <label>
        {{ userform.iAgree }} {{ userform.iAgree.label }}
    </label>
</p>
```

I'm not sure where you want the anchor tag, but being that it's an inline element, you could easily place it beside the label itself.

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested but it is still in two lines.

Comment: You might want to inspect the rendered elements in your browser console to confirm no styles are being applied to the input.

Comment: When I inspect it it looks fine.  It is model form howeer.  <label> <input id="id_iAgree" name="iAgree" required="" type="checkbox"> <label for="id_iAgree">I have read and agree to <a href="/terms/" style="color:red" target="_blank">Terms of Use </a>of the website:</label> </label>

Comment: Wait. Why is label being rendered twice? Can you post the code from your template? It looks like you're using `label_tag` instead of `label`.

Comment: Seems to me it is the Django framework.  Regardless of label or label_tag, the way it's displayed is controlled by the framework.  Not exactly sure how to get around it.

Comment: This isn't true. Your CSS controls display and, to an extent, the HTML. Django gives you the option to output only values, no HTML.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/), you cannot achieve that. But you can [define your own template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/). I.E.

```
def form_print(value):
    return value + value.label
```

Then, you can use it in your template.

```
{{ userform.iAgree|form_print }}
```

Comment: This is an HTML/CSS problem, not a Python problem. A filter is WAY overkill here...

Comment: Hey, It is still a solution that works. Even if it is overkill, it is still an approach to the problem.